# How to clone project from different branch in visual studio 2015?

Tags: github, git-clone

Currently i am worling with github

i have 2 branch in it

1)master

2)Abc

i want to clone project that is in ABC branch

please guide me if you have any idea

**NOTE:"I want to do clone process trough visual studio 2015 because visual studio by default provide github features"**

Thank You.

Comment: Not  duplicate visual studio by default provide GUI feature to clone the project i don't want to write command. if you know how to do this using visual studio please guide me

Comment: If you're learning to use git, I would advise you to force yourself to learn how to use it using the command line. It helps greatly understanding how it works and what you're doing. The various GUI (including the VS one) tend to hide/misname things. That can be quite unsettling for the new git user.

Comment: @Sidewinder94 actually i don't have much time for learning..if you have any idea about visual studio 2015 github then please guide me

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj190809.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 Why not spend some time on the tutorials? Clone the repo and then switch to ABC branch.